# Group by substring

Tags: mysql, group-by, substring

I have a field with text like "`/site/index?sid=18&sub=321333&tid=site.net&ukey=1234543254`".

How can I group it by part of string( '`sid`' url param e.g.)?
And params may be in a different order.(`sid` on the end of line and etc.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at the MySQL string functions:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Especially this looks helpful:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

**UPDATE**

This is exactly what you asked for:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX("/site/index?sid=18&sub=321333&tid=site.net&ukey=1234543254", 'sid=', -1), '&', 1) AS this_will_be_grouped
```

and use `this_will_be_grouped` in the `GROUP BY` clause of your query