# GROUP BY date/month

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that contains a lot of transactions with the date formatted like this:-

```
January 1, 2016
September 9, 2016
September 13, 2016
August 8, 2017
August 9, 2017
```

How would I go about grouping the month and year together, when the date is there in the middle - and they are `Varchar`

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far.

Comment: I can't figure out how to do it as the "day" is in the middle. I've tried the EXTRACT() feature of MySQL. I thought maybe you could explode it, but that would require an extra query of work.

Comment: Take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503393/group-by-substring

Comment: Try converting the field into `DATE` format using the `TO_DATE` function and then use a `GROUP BY` on it. You can also use the `YEAR` and `MONTH` functions after converting it to `DATE`.

Comment: @AniketV `TO_DATE` is an Oracle function, not a MySQL function.

Comment: My bad. Should have mentioned `TIMESTAMP` or `STR_TO_DATE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a slightly tricky question.  We can approach this by first converting your date strings to bona-fide dates using `STR_TO_DATE`, and then going back to strings with `DATE_FORMAT` to obtain the month and year to be used for grouping your data.

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date_col, '%M %e, %Y'), '%Y-%m') AS ym,
    SUM(some_col) AS sum_col
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date_col, '%M %e, %Y'), '%Y-%m')
```

For a better long term solution, consider storing your text dates in some sort of MySQL date column type.  Another option would be to store dates in an numeric column as seconds since the epoch.  The above query, while it may be logically correct, probably has no chance of using any index, so from a performance point of view you should try to avoid situations like this.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Thank you so much. I managed to get it working using this. I'd just say GROUP BY `y-m` instead. :-)

Comment: @Patrick But beware: In most SQL databases an alias defined in the SELECT clause is not available for use in GROUP BY.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(record_date, '%Y%m')
```

Reference [Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)

Comment: You can't use YEAR on that date format 
`SELECT YEAR('January 1, 2016');` returns `(NULL)`

Comment: You can't use DATE_FORMAT `SELECT DATE_FORMAT('January 1, 2016', '%Y%m');` also returns '(null)'