# Group by -SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

My column contains these values.

```
ABCD INC.
ABCD INC REGISTERED 
ABCD ORD SHS
ABCD ORD REGISTERED
```

How can I use correct group by using substring function so my distinct values looks like this?

```
ABCD
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group by substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503393/group-by-substring)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the string up to the first space.  One method uses `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(col, '[^ ]+'), count(*)
from t
group by regexp_substr(col, '[^ ]+');
```

This is a bandage on your real problem, which is having multiple versions of the same name.  You should really implement a look-up table that maps the column values to a canonical name.  This generally requires manual maintenance, but that is the cost of maintaining data integrity.