# Group by variable substring in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, substring

I have a table that contains multiple fields - let's say **FieldA**, **FieldB** etc. and finally **Location**.  The **Location** field has values such as:

```
http://192.168.1.10/location?n=5
http://192.168.1.10/location?n=8
http://192.168.15.6/location?n=1
http://192.168.0.9/location?n=11
http://192.168.15.6/location?n=5
http://192.168.0.9/location?n=6
http://192.168.1.10/location?n=2
```

I need to get the unique values of the IP addresses in the **Location** field.  In other words, from the above example data, I should get

```
http://192.168.1.10
http://192.168.15.6
http://192.168.0.9
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11503556/989468), I am using the following SQL - without much luck

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE FieldA = 'Example' GROUP BY (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX("`table`.Location", "/", 3))
```

The above gives me just a single record. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making judicious use of `SUBSTRING_INDEX`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Location, '/', 3), '/', -1) AS distinct_ips
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

For an explanation on how the above logic works, consider the location value `http://192.168.1.10/location?n=5`.  The inner call to `SUBSTRING_INDEX` returns `http://192.168.1.10`, which is everything to the *left* of the *third* forward slash.  Then, the outer call returns everything to the *right* of the *last* forward slash, which leaves us with the IP address.

Comment: Super!  It works!  Thank you! Would you care to elaborate on HOW it works?  Need the education.  Or perhaps post a link to a "For Dummies" kind of tutorial?

Comment: @Chiwda I have added an explanation.  If you still don't see it, then try exploring more using the demo link I have given in my answer.

Comment: Actually, I was wondering why GROUP BY didn't work and why DISTINCT does.